# Can't "a couple" mean three or four but only two?

Tags: word-meaning

I saw a couple of men walking out of the store.

Is it ok to interpret the phrase a couple of men to be 3 or 4 men, instead of only two?
OR
Does it only mean two, I mean, two man only here?

I think it means two to five, which means it does not mean two only.
Could you help me clarify it?  Thank you always.

Comment: Deborah, you regularly ask questions that could easily be answered by consulting a good dictionary. See this entry from the Cambridge Dictionary: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/couple

Answer (score 0):

I am a non-native myself, and I want to say it can definitely mean more than 2, and up to 4 at least. But more than 4, I can't be sure. I hear it used a lot by native speakers, and many times it's meant more than just 2.

Answer (score 0):

No. To an English speaker, referring to people, a couple would only describe 2. More than that you would have to say "**a few**."

However, when referring to items people will sometimes use "a couple" to mean "a few"

**EXAMPLE:** "I'm going to the grocery store to get a couple of things."

In this case no one assumes you mean exactly 2 items.

Answer (score -1):

Of course it depends on the context and part of speech. As a noun it would mean exactly two. "I saw a couple walking on the beach." As an adjective "I saw a couple of people walking on the sand", it would be 2 to about 5. I would be less likely to say a couple of people if it were five or so people in a tight group than if they were 6 unrelated people.

Comment: in "a couple of people", couple is not an adjective: it is a noun. There are two noun meanings: SOME and TWO PEOPLE. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/couple